# Auth0 React SDK not able to identify returning user with active session

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

My application [enduroco.in](https://www.enduroco.in) uses Auth0 React SDK. The problem I face is that even if I am logged in on 1 tab when I open a new tab and go the home page it doesn't let me know that the user already has an active session.

These are the two lines of code at the start of home component. It works perfectly once I click on login. If the user has a session it doesn't even ask for credentials.

```
function Home(props) {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  if (isAuthenticated) return <Navigate to={"/dashboard"} />;
  else
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Hero />
        <Content />
      </Fragment>
    );
}
```

Desired behavior is that `isAuthenticated` should be true without having to click on login. If thats not possible then need to silently get tokens and if tokens found navigate to dashboard else show the home `<Fragment>`

Comment: Also check for `isLoading`, if the SDK is still _loading_ then you briefly get `isAuthenticated === false`

Comment: Which browser are you using? Your site worked fine for me with both Firefox and Chrome  when opening a new tab. My guess would be that silent auth fails for some reason. This might be relevant: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/issues/101

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti added this code to check isLoading after 5 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
              console.log(
                "redirecting to dashboard",
                isAuthenticated,
                isLoading
              );
            }, 5000)
Gives false for both

Comment: @Boxiom Using Chrome. You need to log in. Then go to another tab and go to home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. It was very straightforward

Just had to set `useRefreshTokens=true` and `cacheLocation="localstorage"` in my Auth0Provider props

It now looks like this

```
const providerConfig = {
  domain: config.domain,
  clientId: config.clientId,
  ...(config.audience ? { audience: config.audience } : null),
  redirectUri: window.location.origin,
  useRefreshTokens: true,
  cacheLocation: "localstorage",
  onRedirectCallback,
};
```